# How to use the escape key to pause/unpause the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes. Game scene where all the game data and objects sit and Main Menu scene.

This script sit on the Game scene and while playing the game when the player press the escape key it's pausing the game and loading the main menu scene and leave also the game scene loaded :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;            
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);            
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is how to make in this script that second time pressing the escape key it will unload the main menu scene and resume the game ? and if the game is paused pressing second time on the escape key in this script will ever work or I need another script with escape key press in the main menu scene ?

Comment: Feel like the answer that was linked to this isn't what was asked. I know I'm way behind but.. the answer to this question is to create a private bool _isPaused; at the class level, if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                _isPaused = !_isPaused;

                if (_isPaused)
                {
                    //Do Pause Logic here
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do Unpause Logic Here      
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making a UI rather than constantly switching between scenes.
Loading large scenes in the future may take unnecessarily long time and this is a disadvantage in terms of optimization.
Your data will be lost during transitions between scenes.
For this reason, you can learn the **Singleton Design Pattern** logic as an alternative. This will allow you to create an indelible object in the transition between scenes. I'm new to unity. As far as i know i tried to answer. I hope I could be useful.

UI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JivuXdrIHK0

Singleton Design Pattern: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpM0C6quQjs